# Slim Reader/Writer locks deadlocking

Tags: c++, winapi, locking, deadlock

For some reason a simple Slim Reader/Writer lock pattern is deadlocking and I don't know why. I have two threads who share the lock (one using exclusive ownership and one using shared ownership).

For some reason, when a second exclusive locking thread is introduced it gets extremely slow for no discernable reason.

my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

SRWLOCK mainLock;
char myglobalvar;
int main()
{
    myglobalvar = '0';
    HANDLE t1 = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, [](void*)->DWORD 
        {
            while (true)
            {
                AcquireSRWLockShared(&mainLock);
                myglobalvar = 'S'; 
                Sleep(500);
                ReleaseSRWLockShared(&mainLock);
            }
            return 0; 
        }, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
    Sleep(50);
    HANDLE t2 = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, [](void*)->DWORD
        {
            while (true)
            {
                AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&mainLock);
                myglobalvar = 'E';
                ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&mainLock);
            }
            return 0;
        }, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&mainLock);
        std::cout << myglobalvar << '\n';
        ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&mainLock);
        Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not deadlocking. Your `t2` thread is in a tight loop of releasing and reacquiring the lock, so it often reacquires the lock again before the other threads (`t1` and the main thread) get any chance to acquire it. The odds at any point in time of `t2` reacquiring the lock before the others do is quite high.  You can improve the odds of the other threads having an opportunity by adding a `Sleep()` with some reasonable value in the loop of `t2`.  Releasing a lock does not cause a thread to yield its timeslice.

Comment: Keep in mind that read-wruite locks are notoriously slow when the exclusive lock is acquired more often than the shared locks.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Slim Reader/Writer (SRW) Locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks)

> Shared mode, which grants shared read-only access to multiple reader
> threads, which enables them to read data from the shared resource
> concurrently.

2. As @Peter said, there is no chance for main thread to acquire the lock because of t2. And your slow feeling is the only `std::cout`.

The following code works fine for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

SRWLOCK mainLock;
char myglobalvar;
int main()
{
    myglobalvar = '0';
    HANDLE t1 = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, [](void*)->DWORD
        {
            while (true)
            {
                AcquireSRWLockShared(&mainLock);
                //myglobalvar = 'S';
                std::cout << myglobalvar << '\n';
                ReleaseSRWLockShared(&mainLock);
                Sleep(250);
            }
            return 0;
        }, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
    Sleep(50);
    HANDLE t2 = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, [](void*)->DWORD
        {
            while (true)
            {
                AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&mainLock);
                myglobalvar = 'E';
                ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&mainLock);
                Sleep(500);
            }
            return 0;
        }, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&mainLock);
        myglobalvar = 'S';
        //std::cout << myglobalvar << '\n';
        ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&mainLock);
        Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: And as **RLWA32-6355** pointed out in [the thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1146252/slim-readerwriter-locks-extremely-slow-violating-f.html), The posted code fails to perform initialization. [*The caller must allocate an SRWLOCK structure and initialize it by either calling InitializeSRWLock (to initialize the structure dynamically) or assign the constant SRWLOCK_INIT to the structure variable (to initialize the structure statically)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks).